Extbase Routing in Backend Module
I have a backend module with an extbase controller.
It seems, that the routing / behaviour regarding Extbase changed in version 13.
Controller (simplified):
#[AsController]
class FormMailController extends ActionController
{

    public function listAction(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        debug($this->request);
    }

    public function downloadCsvAction(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        debug($this->request);
    }

}

I have a button within the list action to navigate to the download action:
$downloadCsvButton = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(GenericButton::class);
                $downloadCsvButton
                    ->setTag('a')
                    ->setHref((string)$uriBuilder->buildUriFromRoute(
                        'formmailsadmin.FormMailController_downloadCsv',
                        [
                            'controller' => 'FormMail',
                            'action' => 'downloadCsv',
                        ]
                    ))
                    ->setTitle('TITLE')
                    ->setLabel('LABEL')
                    ->setShowLabelText(true)
                    ->setIcon($this->iconFactory->getIcon('actions-download'));
    ```

The list action renders correctly, $this->request is initialized. 
But when I click the button to the downloadCsvAction, it throws the following error:


Typed property TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController::$request must not be accessed before initialization

I guess, the generated uri misses some arguments? Or how do I build the link correctly?

